# Understanding U-substitution method to deal with compound integral functions

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I am starting to learn Integrals by using *u-substitution* method and I came across an example in which there is a part I don't quite understand.

Let's suppose I have got this Integral here:
$$ \int (3x²+ 2x){e^{(x^3 + x^2)}}dx $$ 
Then, I set u to be equal to:
$$ u = x^3 + x^2 $$

Then the derivative of ***u*** is simply:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}= 3x^2 + x $$

So far, so good, the problem for me is now:

$$(\partial x)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}= (3x^2 + x)(\partial x) $$

It seems like both sides of the equation were multiplied by $$(\partial x) $$

Therefore becoming this:
$$\partial u = (3x^2 + x)(\partial x) $$

It doesn't make any sense whatsoever in my mind: ***DX is not a number***, it cannot be treated as so and be multiplied in both sides to obtain ***DU***. Correct if I am wrong but, ***DX*** is the length of that little rectangle that we are summing when tackling integrals by using Riemmans' sum, right?

Could you guys be so kind as to explain to me why we can do this maneuver?

Thanks in advance, I really appreciate it

Comment: Well, you're supposed to differentiate both sides with respect to x, not take the partial derivative.

Comment: So are you saying length is not a number?

Comment: yeah, DX in this context is the change in X, right? And since the derivative is the change in x going to zero and so is the change y, it means that DX is the change is X (Minimum change) and is in fact a number, right? That is the reason why I can multiply both sides by it. btw, both sides were actually multiplied, were not them?

Comment: Check the line before "so far, so good..."

Comment: One way to look at it is that the $u$ substitution is to the chain rule as integration by parts is to the product rule.

Answer (score 1):

You're not really multiplying both sides by $dx$.  The definition of "differential" is

$$dy = f'(x) \; dx.$$

Another symbol for $f'(x)$ is $\frac{dy}{dx},$ so the definition can be written

$$dy = \frac{dy}{dx} \; dx,$$

where it's understood that $dy/dx$ is a symbol for the derivative and not $dy$ divided by $dx$.

So you start with

$$\frac{du}{dx} = 3x^3+2x$$

then multiply both sides by $dx$

$$\frac{du}{dx}\; dx = (3x^3+2x) \; dx.$$

Now the left side is $du$ by *definition* of differential.  You didn't cancel the $dx$'s.

Comment: When you say "differential", are you talking about "Differential equations"? Thanks for your reply, by the way

Comment: No.  A symbol like $dx$ is called a differential.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function

Comment: Thanks, @B.Goddard! 

Just to see if I got this straight, ok? *dx/dy* can also be expressed as Δy / Δx, which is the same as the change in _y_ over the change in _x_ . Ok, but let's say that I don't have the Δy, I have just the slope of the function (f prime) and Δx, then through these data, I can figure out what my Δy was to give me that slope with that change in x ... is my understanding right?

Comment: It's roughly the right idea, but there are some problems.  We usually think of $dx$ and $dy$ as new variables.  IF we set $dx = \Delta x$, then $dy$ will be approximately $\Delta y$.   The deltas are the actual change along the curvy function.  The $d$'s are the change along the tangent line.  When things are small, these are almost the same.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time and your sharing. Would you happen to have a video or book recommendation? Or if not, what should I type in the google to look this up, e.g "Differential explanation"

Comment: I think any Calc text should have a section on "Approximation by differentials."  Or "Linear approximation."

Answer (score 0):

You can just think of being $$\int f'(x)*e^{f(x)} dx$$ Some people like to call $f'(x) dx$ $df$.